# 2 or more viewcontrollers with same swift class crash

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

Hello I have multiple veiwcontorllers in my storyboard and when they have the same class (for exmaple viewocntorller.swift) and code like
changing background color they crash with

```
EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_1386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
```

Is there some way to fix this without using separate .swift files for each viewcontroller

Here are screenshot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8I2IB.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WW19m.png)

Has you can see the viewcontroller are in same class

Comment: viewocntorller is a very odd name for a view controller :o That aside, can you show us what you've done by showing a screenshot and some code?

Comment: sorry for my spelling i am using the default view controller name

Comment: class and file names are different things, you can have multiple class in the same swift file.
Please provide an sample of code.

Comment: @thibautnoah  done update

Comment: @Eendje done updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's not the error of viewController. It means that your **button reference** is not there. It's **nil**. Verify that it's properly created.
May be you've button outlet of one xib and not the other. and when for your xib (with no button), viewDidLoad is called, button is nil. 
If you have buttons in both, then properly attach outlet. otherwise, make this button optional

Comment: i am new what is this? i have already made ibooutlet and used it

Comment: what's your 2nd view that's using viewController? Does it have button as well?

Comment: See, the simplest solution is to have different viewcontroller for both your views as they are not same. (I'm suggesting this as i guess, you don't have knowledge of optionals etc. But don't worry, this is simple and you'll learn :) ) Let me know, if you still face any issue @user3705265

Comment: how to i make it optional?

Comment: first of all disconnect this outlet. now change '!' to '?'. then connect your button with this outlet (that is already mentioned in your swift file). Now while setting button's color, use "button?" instead of "button"

Comment: depends on what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a button on your second view controller in your storyboard.
Since you have an outlet to that button (the one on the first view controller) inside your code (linked to both viewcontrollers) and you specify a color for it your code will crash, because there is no button, calling a nil reference = crash.

To solve this you can add a button on the second view.

An outlet is not a basic optional, you are in fact telling the compiler that this button will NEVER be nil, that is what we call an Implicitly Unwrapped Optional.

Comment: is there anyway to not have button on other viewocntorller

Comment: Dunno if fayza's solution works, if that doesn't and you still want to use same class for both views, you could put an id on the view and depending on the id create a button in code or not.